# Can't get values from the store ngrx

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx, ngrx-store

I'm facing NgRx and I can't understand how could be so hard add a value to the store and retrieve it. Anyway, that's what I have done so far

Effects ts:

```
export class idEffects {

    saveId$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$
        .pipe(
            ofType(idActions.addIdAction),
            tap(payload => {
                console.log("action",payload);
            })
        )
    ,{dispatch: false});

    constructor(
      private actions$: Actions
    ) {}
  }
```

Actions ts:

export const ADD_ID = '[Id Action] add id';

```
export const addIdAction = createAction(
    ADD_ID,
    props<{id: any}>()
)
```

Reducer ts:

```
export interface IdState {
    id: any;
}

export const defaultId: IdState = {
    id: undefined
};

export const idReducer = createReducer (
    defaultId,

    on(idActions.addIdAction, (state, action) => {
        //console.log("Calling id reducer", action);
        return {
            id: action
        }
    })
)
```

and the Selector ts:

```
export const selectIdState = 
createFeatureSelector<IdState>("id")

export const selectIdValue = createSelector(
    selectIdState,
    id => id
);
```

Now, that's what I have in my app.module.ts

```
StoreModule.forRoot({id: idReducer}),
    EffectsModule.forRoot([IdEffects]),
    StoreModule.forRoot(reducers, {
      metaReducers
    }),
    StoreDevtoolsModule.instrument({maxAge: 25}),
    StoreRouterConnectingModule.forRoot({
      stateKey: 'router',
      routerState: RouterState.Minimal
    })
```

It seems that the storing data is working well because the Redux panel in my console return this:

```
id(pin):"1"
data(pin):"Hello There"
type(pin):"[Id Action] add id"
```

But, when I try to retrieve this object I get an `undefined` and I do it in this way:

```
this.id$ = storeId.pipe(select(selectIdValue))
```

and in the html

```
<h4>The id obj is: {{id$ | async}}</h4>
```

But it doesn't write anything. I tried to get the result using a subscribe in the component, and it gets me `undefined` how could be possibile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the state is

```js
export interface IdState {
    id: any;
}
```

therefore selector should select id from its feature state

```js
export const selectIdValue = createSelector(
    selectIdState,
    state => state.id, // selectIdState returns an object of IdState interface.
);
```

then, the reducer, it should add the `id` prop to the state, not an `action`

```js
    on(idActions.addIdAction, (state, action) => {
        //console.log("Calling id reducer", action);
        return {
            ...state, // not needed in your case, but a good style.
            id: action.id, // <- .id
        }
    }),
```

the effect, it's not needed and you can remove it.

and the last thing the `reducers` variable. Could you share its source?
It should be

```js
const reducers = {
  id: idReducer, // id key is important, idReducer is enough for now.
};
```

and don't forget to dispatch somewhere `addIdAction`.
for example in `ngOnInit` of a component.

```js
this.store.dispatch(addIdAction({id: 'value'}));
```

If you have things like that - it should work.
Let me know if you have more questions.

Comment: Thank you! It's working. I'm a bit confused about the use of NgRx sometimes. Assuming I this.store.dispatch(addIdAction({id: 'value'})); to save the id in a click function. Then, in the same component, I want to check if the id value exists in the store. I just call the select function and then i can use the subscribe method to get the value from the observable. If exists, I just print the value otherwise I add again the value with dispatch. But when I click the observable is fired, conclusion, I get a loop. I don't know I can i do to solve it

Comment: I would say if you want to print the value - the best way would be the `async` pipe. Post a question, ping me there or share its link here as a comment and I'll take a look. Imagine you have a current user in your app and you need this data in several components. When the app is loaded we dispatch an action to load current user and then all components can use it, that's the idea of ngrx, share data among the whole app.